# Flex Deploy [IOErrorEvent type=“ioError” bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text=“Error #2032”]

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I deployed a flex php application for my own use at my server: "www.app.gisla.in". When It was under development and testing on localhost, it was working all fine. But when I deployed it a HTTP service is causing error. It is saying

> HTTP Request Error [IOErrorEvent type=“ioError” bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text=“Error #2032”] URL:http://www.app.gisla.in/tcpdf/examples/gis23.php

I searched and found out that maybe it lacked crossdomain.xml file. I created and uploaded the crossdomain.xml having all all access to all (*).

But still the problem persist.

(I am sharing the password of the app: Username: admin, password: admin
Go to PreInspect ---> Search --->Click View/Edit on any item--->click save n next--->next--->**CLICK SAVE N GENERATE REPORT**
Here at botton click I am invoking http service for creating pdf via TCPDF(http://www.app.gisla.in/tcpdf/examples/gis23.php)

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to incorrect arguements.

Comment: I am just passing single String argument